# Convert $_GET variables to $_POST paypal to hide return url

Tags: php, post, paypal

I want to Convert `$_GET` variables to `$_POST` paypal to hide return url

```
<?      
    //i want Convert $_GET variables to $_POST paypal to hide return url

    $return = 'http://my site. com/tks.php?id=150';
    $mypost='cmd=_cart&currency_code=USD&business=email@gmail.com&tax_cart=0.00&handling_cart=0.00&charset=utf-8
    &item_name_1=IDM Download Manager(4)&quantity_1=1&amount_1=5.00&item_number_1=1&option_index_0=0&return='.$return;

    // this $mypost will be post to $posted url 
    // i don't want this method $posturl = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?$mypost';

    $posturl = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?';

    header("Location: $posturl");        
?>
```

Comment: can't hide the return url and the information you are sending with return URL, good way is save them in database and only pass the id of the row with the return url and get the save data from database if you want to show detail on return page Note: you can encode and decode the ID.

Comment: @Shehary i got your idea but the payment made then return to my site automatically send items to buyer if the return is by server side  post to paypal  not be seen to client but GET method easy tracking and the return and without payment copying return url get item without payment.

Comment: you are missing `response from paypal` let's say you pass the id with url and if buyer pay via paypal and payment get through, there is another file where you receive response from paypal the payment status and other transaction details so in very same response file (php) you can update the saved record (which you saved before sending buyer to paypal) against the response you get from paypal and then show the detail on return url that if payment get through or if there is any transaction issues etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuery` and encode `$return` to `JSON` on client side and post it to server using `POST` method type.

Comment: how? give sample @hammad Raza (: talk talk

Comment: Use something like this

Comment: jQuery('#yourButton').on('click', function () {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'server.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {'return': yourUrl}};
and on server side receive it as $_POST['return'];